# Should i release maven library if one of its dependency changed?

Tags: maven, versioning, release-management

I have few libraries, some of them depend on another. So for eg:

A 1.0.0
No dependencies

B 1.0.0
Depends ON: A 1.0.0

Question is:

If i release A with 1.0.1 and this release is backward compatible with 1.0.0 should i release B?

Comment: If your can guarantee that A with 1.0.1 is backward compatible with 1.0.1 there is no need to release a new version of B. You should make clear in your version schema that 1.0.1 means a bugfix and 1.1.0 means enhance but backward compatible (semantical versioning)...Only a good hint in your documentation for the users of A should be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can depend a lot on the specifics of the code and how the artifacts are deployed, but in general, you need to release B to make the code changes in A visible.

- Assume B is a jar artifact, and another client has a `<dependency>` on that artifact.  That means that the client also has a transitive dependency on A, but at the specific version that was expressed in the `<dependency>` in B.  Taking your example, the client has a dependency on B 1.0.0, which itself has a dependency on A 1.0.0, so the client will pick up A 1.0.0 transitively.  In order to publish a bug fix in A to this client, you need to release B 1.0.1 with its `<dependency>` on A updated to point to A 1.0.1.
- Assume B is a war artifact deployed in a web application container.  Each jar `<dependency>` used by the web application is shipped inside the `lib` directory of the built war.  In order to publish a bug fix in A to this web application, you need to release B 1.0.1 with its `<dependency>` on A updated to point to A 1.0.1.

In the first example, (client depends on B as a jar), a possible workaround is for the client to override the version of A by adding its own explicit `<dependency>` on A, perhaps using a version range for flexibility to pick up the latest released version.  This can cause maintenance pitfalls though, because it means the client is combining a version of A and a version of B that were not tested together as part of the B build.  In general, it's preferrable to release B, but if it is difficult to release B, then this can be a viable short-term workaround.

More details on transitive dependencies and version range syntax are available here:

- [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)
- [Enforcer Version Range Specification](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html)

Comment: thank you Chris! The main point is "In general, it's preferrable to release B, but if it is difficult to release B, then this can be a viable short-term workaround." I think i will release B, it's not difficult

Comment: I would prevent using version ranges, cause that's makes your build not reproducible anymore...better explicit overwrite the dependency....the nearest dependency wins...

Comment: @khmarbaise, yes, i don't like range versioning either